# A service is not communicating with activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I'm creating a service which is started, but no communication is received via broadcast. I suspected that there was something wrong with IntentFilter and names, but it all seems correct.

I've been studying example from [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)  (par. 8)

What have I done wrong? **Why broadcast is not received by MainActivity?**

MainActivity

```
package com.jackslastssid;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    class MainActivityAfterCaller extends AfterCaller {
        public void callback() {
            update_something();
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Daemon called back! :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // never happend
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(SayHelloDaemon.NOTIFICATION));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

SayHelloDaemon:

```
public class SayHelloDaemon extends IntentService {

    public static final String NOTIFICATION = "com.jackslastssid.SayHelloDaemon";

    public SayHelloDaemon() {
        super("SayHelloDaemon");
    }

    class SayHelloDaemonAfterCaller extends AfterCaller {
        public void callback() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
    // will be called asynchronously by Android
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        new SayHelloAsyncTask().execute(new Pair<AfterCaller, Map>(new SayHelloDaemonAfterCaller(), Data.getInstance().getQueryMap()));
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jackslastssid" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".SayHelloDaemon"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/service_name"
            android:exported="false"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Where you start service ?

Comment: Do not use Toast to debug the application. Use log and see if it is printed or not

Comment: How do you know that `onReceive()` is not being called?

Comment: @DavidWasser i have toasted a string in onResponse function, and have never seen it

Comment: Toast is not a reliable debugging method. Please add logging or set breakpoints in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't started the service in the activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SayHelloDaemon.class);
startService(intent);
```

Comment: I have started it, but nothing happens. It's just in another function, which i haven't written here. Thanks nevertheless